# convert dask dataframe to dataframe is too slow, it does not save time when using it parallel process

Tags: pandas, dask

`import pandas as pd
    import dask.dataframe as dd
    import time`

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')


data['x'] = range(1000)
data['y'] = range(1000)

def add(s):
    s['sum'] = s['x']+s['y']
    return s
start = time.time()
n_data = data.apply(add, axis=1)
print('it cost time is {} sec'.format(time.time()-start))

start = time.time()
d_data = dd.from_pandas(data, npartitions=10)
s_data = d_data.apply(add, axis=1)
print('it cost time is {} sec'.format(time.time()-start))
start = time.time()
s_data = s_data.compute()
print('but transform it cost time is {} sec'.format(time.time()-start))
```

the result is :

> it cost time is 1.0297248363494873 sec
>
> it cost time is 0.008629083633422852 sec
>
> but transform it cost time is 1.3664238452911377 sec

Comment: The first time for dask is just the time to setup the processing pipeline. The second time is the actual execution time because only when the whole pipeline is setup and you call execute dask computes the results. There may be some additional overhead, so this only makes sense when you have a lot of data. Otherwise better stick to pandas. Also have a look at the [official documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) where the dask graph is explained in more detail. If you really need to improve performance let me know the details what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas apply is slow.  Because you operate row-by-row with a Python function it has to use Python for loops rather than C for loops.

Dask dataframe's default scheduler uses threads, which are usually very good for fast vectorized Pandas operations, but won't help for slow Pandas operations that are bound by Python code.  You could consider trying the multiprocessing or distributed schedulers.   See http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html

However, I encourage you use Pandas better before you try Dask.  Probably using fast Pandas APIs can accelerate your computation much more than Dask can.